# How to completely remove timeshift?

Tags: 20.04, backup, system, restore, timeshift

I installed Timeshift backup and Restore manager for my Ubuntu 20.04 and I interrupted the backup. Now I uninstalled the Timeshift but the folder still exists under the root with 15 GB of storage, And also there are many timeshift files in many locations. So How can I remove them all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove the folder, open a terminal and enter the command

```
sudo rm -rf /path/to/folder
```

Then type your password, followed by <kbd>enter</kbd>

Here `path/to/folder` may be `/home/timeshift` or just `/timeshift`. Correctly check the path before you enter the command.

To find all the timeshift files (which are outside `/home/timeshift`), enter the command `locate timeshift`, and it would show the locations of all files/folders having the name `timeshift`. Then you can remove them (one by one if the number of such folders is not large, or with a bash script, if there are too many folders).

Comment: Thank's a bunch. I did the same As you told I removed every file every folder but still when I locate timeshift I get those results that are already deleted by me

Comment: @AmitNikhade That's probably because the computer is still using the old database (which is updated every 24 hours). To regenerate the database, enter the command `sudo updatedb`. Once that is done, check if `locate timeshift` shows anything.

Comment: great.. bro. thank's a lot

Comment: @AmitNikhade My pleasure

Comment: this solution didn't work, still cannot delete the folder of timeshift. I have it on external drive.

Comment: @doctorate do you have write access to the external drive? What did not work? Can you ask a new question with exactly what you did?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi, it turned out that my external drive had errors, which were fixed after running `sudo fsck /drive` twice. So after that, I could delete snapshots as usual.